# SQL Server 2017 Express Edition - Installing Error 2147467259 (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: installation, sql-server-2017

I am installing SQL Server Express Edition 2017 in a Dell Laptop Intel Core i7-5600U CPU 2.6 GH and 8GB RAM. Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bits. And I just keep on getting the error: "The system couldn´t find the path specified" Decimal error code 2147467259.
I had Visual Studio 2017, I uninstalled it and uninstalled the Visual C++ redistributables, but I still can´t install the SQL 2017. Any idea about what else to do would be greately appreciated.